# Has the bootoption "acpi=noirq" any disadvantages in permanent use? Help me with debugging acpi pls

Tags: boot, 64-bit, uefi, acpi

I am using Ubuntu for a while now and I have an average knowledge of it, I thought so ;), but have a problem I cant solve alone. I did a lot of research, but now I cant find an other solution and I hope you can help me!

**I want to know if the bootoption "acpi=noirq" has big disadvantages other than problems with sleep mode or will my hardware suffer from this bootoption??? To install and run 14.04 Ubuntu I have to set this option. I want to install it on a new UEFI pc**

I have to set the bootoption because:
I bougth a new coumputer and wanted to install ubuntu on it as dualboot option. The installer broke every time, when I should get the options to partionate the Disk:

After booting into the Live CD I saw that the problem was, that the kernel.log and syslog incresed, until all the RAM(16GByte) was full. In both logfiles, 3 lines were repeated:

```
ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND 
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed 
(another Line I cant remember and find in the internet)
```

When I install Ubuntu these lines and steady increasing of the logfiles would kill my SSD very fast, so I have to search for a workaround.

After debugging ACPI like described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI) I got this results:

- **acpi=off** -> All working fine/No Errors in logfiles, but I read, that you shouldnt set this option permanent because of big problems
- **acpi=ht** -> Not working. Same problem, Logfiles reach the RAM end.
- **acpi=noirq** or **pci=noacpi** -> Working good. The Errors appear still, but the error lines are only repeated 100 times at every
  boot(not endless repeating). Then the errors stop and it seems all
  working correct then. It seems to me, that acpi for irq doesnt cause
  the problem(because by disabling this option the error also appears
  100 times), but the acpi for irq leads to the endless repeating of
  it. I dont know a lot of irq, but i read that its for internal
  messaging/routing between internal components like proccessor and
  ram. **So could be perhaps the problem that a message is going around
  all the time, without getting an answer or finding the destination,
  and everytime this is logged? Did I undestand that rigth?!**
- **All other acpi bootoptions** -> not working

I thought, that perhaps the problem is with the computer: It is designed to consume less power. Unusually it has 2 external power supplies, perhaps this could lead to problems with the acpi interface, implemented by ASUS. But I discovered in the Internet a lot of other users having problems with acpi, since updating to 14.04.

Further I read (from the acpi debugging site): "If acpi=off works and acpi=ht fails, then the issue is in the ACPI table parsing code itself, or perhaps the SMP code." This doesnt help me to solve the problem by myself.

***It would be nice if you could answer my big questions(written fat above and here again) and perhaps help with the problem:***

1. I want to know if the bootoption "acpi=noirq" has big disadvantages other than problems with sleep mode or will my hardware suffer from this bootoption??? To install and run 14.04 Ubuntu I have to set this option
2. So could be perhaps the problem that a message is going around all the time, without getting an answer or finding the destination, and everytime this is logged? Did I undestand that rigth?!
3. Otherwise perhaps an acpi expert could give me an other solution or give a clue to solve the problem?
4. I want to install Ubuntu on a new UEFI computer. When I am booting from the DVD there ligths quickly an error and disappears after that very fast: Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi". Then I come to the EFI installation selection. I read that this schould be not a problem. I doesnt think it has something to do with the acpi error, but I wanted to write this down. I think that I can ignore that error, because I already choose the efi partition to install grup later in installation process, rigth?!

My english isn't very good, but I hope you understood the problem and my questions. The problem took me a lot of time for research, search in the internet and to write this, so I hope you can help me. :)

Best regards,