# ACPI tables/DSDT tables not available in Ubuntu 14.04. How to restore?

Tags: 64-bit, uefi, acpi

I am working now for 3 weeks at following problem. I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a new ASUS UEFI PC. Here was my first problem description with a question, but nobody answered:

[Has the bootoption "acpi=noirq" any disadvantages in permanent use? Help me with debugging acpi pls](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577769/has-the-bootoption-acpi-noirq-any-disadvantages-in-permanent-use-help-me-with)

Meantime I installed Ubuntu14.04(same problems with 12.04) with bootoption: acpi=noirq for installation. After Installation I wanted to run it with the same bootoption, which is not as bad as acpi=off. But after installatoin its not possible to run without: acpi=off.

If not booting with acpi=off following lines spam my syslog and kern.log until the disk is full(50GB in 1 hour). Very bad for SSD...

```
ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L06] (20140926/evgpe-581)
ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.GSSE] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20140926/psargs-559)
ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L06] (Node ffff392a2f003), AE_NOT_FOUND (20140926/psparse-536)
```

In the meantime I read a lot about irq, acpi and dsdt tables. First I thougth, there is a problem with bad implementation of ACPI and DSDT Tables from ASUS and namespace ae_not_found is missing in the dsdt table.

**But now I understood the problem:
There is no DSDT Table and other ACPi Tables?! Under /sys/firmware/acpi there is nothing?!**

Ok, so Linux cant access the tables and so there is the namespace missing error in table, bacause indeed there is no table and no namespace...

***Now I want to know how to get the tables there? Is it possible to extract it from the UEFi and insert it there? What can I do?!***

Perhaps will it help to install Ubuntu in legacy(BIOS) and not in UEFI mode?! I would have to reinstall so windows, too.

I am getting sick of this error. I used Ubuntu for 2 years, but I am searching now for 3 weeks for that error. I am close to delete ubuntu and get back to clear windows...

Update:
To make more clear. I decompiled the ACPI Tables and found only entries for Windows. Seems that BIOS/UEFI ACPI interface is wrong implementated into it. I have already installed the latest BIOS. Any othter ideas?!